# get current db session using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session

My project is developed using hibernate 3.6 with hades library/spring/tomcat. I have a method that is annotated as @Transactional and performs db operations using dao object that extends GenericDao class from hades lib. Please advice how can i retrieve currentSession statically from this class?

http://hades.synyx.org/static/2.x/site/org.synyx.hades/apidocs/org/synyx/hades/dao/GenericDao.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The link point to an interface. You can't get anything from an interface that you implement. If, in fact, you extend its [unique implementation](http://hades.synyx.org/static/2.x/site/org.synyx.hades/apidocs/org/synyx/hades/dao/orm/GenericJpaDao.html), you have access to the entity manager thanks to the [`getEntityManager()`](http://hades.synyx.org/static/2.x/site/org.synyx.hades/apidocs/org/synyx/hades/dao/orm/GenericDaoSupport.html#getEntityManager%28%29) method.

You can do nearly everything you would do with a Hibernate session using an EntityManager. It's the equivalent in the standard JPA API. If you really need to access the underlying Hibernate session, call [`unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#unwrap%28java.lang.Class%29).